# How to find the information from the hosting service 1&1 in order to send emails using PHP mailer?

Tags: php, hosting, phpmailer, web-hosting

I currently have a website which uses PHPmailer to send emails. I am hosting it with 1&1.fr, but cannot find the information in order to actually send emails. Here is the following information that I need:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
```

On the 1&1.fr website, they give out the following information:

[image: server info]

In the image, they specify multiple ports as well as an entrance/exit server; which ones am I supposed to pick and enter into my PHP file.

The rest of my code works fine (it works when I use my gmail account using 000webhost).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have the answers in the image you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I know that the information should be in the image, but I don't understand well enough the difference between the different ports / servers to know which configuration to use for PHPmailer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// define the $mail // just in case you miss it as it is missing in your code.
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;    // this is to enable debug if there are errors

$mail->isSMTP();         //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'auth.smtp.1and1.fr';

// Enable authentication so you must provide username and password for SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  

$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';     // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';               // SMTP password

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                // Here you are telling to use a secure connection with TLS/SSL

//Set the SMTP port number
$mail->Port = 587; // if specified tls. try also 465 as defined in the picture you post

// TCP port for secure connections. 465 is the secure port for outgoing 
// emails and 993 is for incoming email using IMAP. If you use POP3 the 
//incoming emails are received on 995 port number.
```

Hope now is more clear.

Comment: This is incorrect; `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` will not work on port 465. Either change `SMTPSecure` to `ssl` or change `Port` to 587, so the info provided in the question should be workable - most ISPs support both mechanisms, but you can't mix them.

Comment: @Sigma Thanks! This is actually very helpful! I just have one followup question: are the SMTP username and password those for my 1&1 email address? For some reason, even after entering the above information, the emails still don't send.

Comment: @Synchro I've tried with both ssl and tls, but it's still not working properly

Comment: @Syncro thanks, my mistake, according that that most uses both TLS/SSL to avoid errors most have an automatic redirect to port 587 when is used secure connection and erroneous specified TLS. Thanks for catch. ps: corrected :)

Comment: You need to define "not working properly" for us to be able to help.

Comment: @Synchro the page just keeps loading forever. If the email had been sent, another webpage would be loaded; instead it remains stuck on the previous page, trying to send the email.

Comment: Please can you post all the code from page and in case the code of the page that is calling/using the send mail page to understand better and look for any error. Thanks

Comment: If it's timing out it's most likely a network block or wrong address. Use the suggestions in [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) to diagnose it.